# Problem importing CSV Timestamp Column into postgresql - Invalid Format?

Tags: postgresql, csv, timestamp, dbeaver

I am trying to import a CSV file into a Windows 14.2 version of postgresql, using dBeaver v23.0.0 and its UI Import process, but receive the following error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "04 Feb 2022 09:18:23:667"
```

I  have tried defining the destination database column as both `timestamp` and `timestamptz` but that did not make a difference.  The date/time string looks good to me, and the same CSV file imports into MS SQL Server just fine (sigh).

What am I missing?

Comment: why not use proper iso format dates dates, so that postgres can understand it

Comment: Because I do not generate the CSV file, it is given to me 'as is' from the source system

Comment: every conversion needs a lot of time, whch will cost dearly in big databases, so try to get proper dates if all possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show datestyle; 
SQL, MDY 

select '04 Feb  09:18:23:667 2022'::timestamp;  
invalid input syntax for type timestamp ... 

select '04 Feb  09:18:23.667 2022'::timestamp; 
02/04/2022 09:18:23.667.
```

The issue is the `:` in `... 23:667 ...`.
Not sure how MS SQL Server deals with that as the examples I see all use `.`.

The solutions are:

1. Change that `:` to `.` in the file.
2. Import the CSV data into a staging table and then transfer to final table using something like:

```
select to_timestamp('04 Feb  09:18:23:667 2022', 'DD Mon HH:MI:SS:MS YYYY');
02/04/2022 09:18:23.667 PST
```

Where `to_timestamp()` comes from [Data Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). On that page look for *Table 9.27. Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting* to see what the template patterns mean.